# How to align output?

Tags: c++, text-alignment

How to align the output?

I tried this

```
  for(int x = 0; i<5; i++)
  cout<<a[x]<<setw(5)<<"|"<<setw(5)<<b[x]<<endl;
```

If all of a have same char length then the output like this

```
 frd     |     hehe
 asd   |     hoho
 .....
 .....
```

But if not have same length

```
 frd     |     hehe
 asdfg     |     hohoo
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try setting the width *before* printing the thing you want aligned?

Comment: @Scott Hunter No, how?

Comment: @Frd Like so `cout<<setw(5)<<a[x]<<" | "<<setw(5)<<b[x]<<endl;`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ but isn't it same with the code i tried above?

Comment: @Frd Not that's not the same.

Comment: `std::cout << std::left  << std::setw(5) << a[x] << " | " << b[x] << '\n';`?? Then don't forget `std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::left)`.

Comment: Also, in your first example, `a[0]` and `a[1]` cannot have the same length as the example suggests. There `"frd  "` is stored with additional `whitespace` (or `"asd\b"` is stored with an embedded `backspace`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your suggested code:

```
    cout<<a[x]<<setw(5)<<"|"<<setw(5)<<b[x]<<endl;
```

you have two problems that are leading to misalignment. (1) you have not provided any width for `a[x]` so it will be output without any adjustment; and (2) depending on the alignment you seek, the default justification when a width is specified for `std::cout` will be `right` justified.

(additionally, as noted in my comment, in your first example, `a[0]` and `a[1]` cannot have the same length as the example suggests. There `"frd  "` is stored with additional `whitespace` (or `"asd\b"` is stored with an embedded `backspace`) otherwise the output of `"a[x]|"` would be aligned.)

To provide alignment for the output of both `a` and `b`, you must specify, at minimum, the width of `a[x]` with `std::setw(n)`. Further, unless you want `a[x]` aligned to the right of the field created by `std::setw(5)`, you must control the justification by setting [std::ios_base::fmtflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) with `std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::left)` (or simply `std::left`). See [std::setiosflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags).

When you set a format flag for the stream, you are setting bits in a *Bitmap* type that will remain set after the current call to `std::cout` completes. So to tidy up after yourself and restore the flag state of the stream to default, you either (1) have to save the `fmtflags` for the stream with by capturing all flags with `std::ios_base::fmtflags` or (2) you must reset the individual flag you set with `std::resetiosflags(...)`.

So if I understand your question and your request for alignment (though it is unclear how you want `b[x]` aligned), you could align both `a` and `b` with left justification by:

```
    std::cout << "left justified output (both a & b)\n\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::left  << std::setw(5) 
                << a[i] << " | " << b[i] << '\n';
```

or you could align `a` with left justification and then restore the default flag state letting `b` be output with default (right) justification, e.g.

```
    std::cout << "\nleft justified output for a, default for b\n\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::left  << std::setw(5) 
                << a[i] << " | " << std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::left) 
                << std::setw(5) << b[i] << '\n';
```

Putting that altogether in an example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    std::vector<std::string> a = { "frd", "asdfg", "asd", "quack" }, 
                             b = { "hehe", "hohoo", "haloo", "hack" };

    std::cout << "left justified output (both a & b)\n\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::left  << std::setw(5) 
                << a[i] << " | " << b[i] << '\n';

    std::cout << "\nleft justified output for a, default for b\n\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::left  << std::setw(5) 
                << a[i] << " | " << std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::left) 
                << std::setw(5) << b[i] << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/setwstring
left justified output (both a & b)

frd   | hehe
asdfg | hohoo
asd   | haloo
quack | hack

left justified output for a, default for b

frd   |  hehe
asdfg | hohoo
asd   | haloo
quack |  hack
```

**Note:** if you want to make multiple changes to flags within the course of an output operation and then restore ALL format flags to their original state, you can use:

```
    std::ios_base::fmtflags f = std::cout.flags (); // save ios_base flags
    // do output, set flags as desired
    std::cout.flags (f);                            // restore saved flags
```

Let me know if this addresses the alignment you were attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the setw(#) with any number you need.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a[5] = {"afdfadsf","ggrggeee","fdsafsda","erererefdsfd","sdfdsfdffdf"};
    string b[5] = {"fdsfdsfd", "fdsfdsaffdf","fdsfsadfdfd","rererrefdfd","zzzzzzzfdfd"};
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        cout << left << setw(15) << a[i] << left << setw(15) << b[i] <<  endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using printf. Seriously, it works.

eg:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    printf("%-10s | %10s\n", "asd", "asdad");
    printf("%-10s | %10s\n", "asd", "adad");
    printf("%-10s | %10s\n", "adsada", "adad");
    printf("%-10s | %10s\n", "addasda", "adad");
    printf("%-10s | %10s\n", "asdsd", "dad");
    printf("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n", "asdsd", "dad");
    printf("%-10s | %-10s\n", "asd", "asdad");
    printf("%-10s | %-10s\n", "asd", "adad");
    printf("%-10s | %-10s\n", "adsada", "adad");
    printf("%-10s | %-10s\n", "addasda", "adad");
    printf("%-10s | %-10s\n", "asdsd", "dad");
}
```

Gives

```
asd        |      asdad
asd        |       adad
adsada     |       adad
addasda    |       adad
asdsd      |        dad
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
asd        | asdad     
asd        | adad      
adsada     | adad      
addasda    | adad      
asdsd      | dad
```

Comment: No complaints about `printf`, yes -- it does work, and usually much faster than `iostream`, but generally when answering questions tagged C++, the C solution is not what is being requested if a C++ solution exists for the problem. No dings for this answer, but just be aware of that general proposition going forward -- it will save you a few DVs by others.

Comment: yeah I find that when I forget the one of the aligns in the << and have a 400 + char line to do something with printf that takes a lot less space then I go for printf. Techincally its not pure c++, its using cstdio but then again the code is using arrays of strings or arrays of char* or god forbid 2D arrays, which would suggest that the answer might be something that they are more comforable with.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't display formatted text? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @L.F. I disagree. I say to you that it does answer the question.

Comment: @LindaLambie The OP wants to learn how to use I/O manipulators. Your answer is technically correct, but bypassing the key problem and using another approach altogether is probably not the kind of answer the OP is looking for.